# Heroku react app build failed (node-sass)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, node-sass

- the last build was working and only UI changes in this build.
- I only changed the device I'm working with, so maybe I forgot to download something.
- I don't know why this isn't working.
- I failed to solve this problem in anyway.

"node-sass": "^5.0.0",

**first part from the Build Log:**

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: mars/create-react-app
-----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
=====> Detected Framework: Multipack
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
=====> Detected Framework: Node.js
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  >=10
       engines.npm (package.json):   >=6
       
       Resolving node version >=10...
       Downloading and installing node 16.0.0...
       Bootstrapping npm >=6 (replacing 7.10.0)...
       npm >=6 installed
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code 1
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_a9056f2a/node_modules/node-sass
       npm ERR! command failed
       npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
       npm ERR! Building: /tmp/build_a9056f2a/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_a9056f2a/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
```

Comment: I had faced a similar issue a year ago, I solved it by installing the node-sass in dependencies rather than dev dependency. It is/maybe a workaround, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

Node version support policy for node-sass:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: Right, Node 16 isn't currently supported